# Matrix inequality with maximum singular value

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $P$ be a positive definite matrix: $P = P^\top \succ 0$.

For any square matrix $A$, show that the matrix inequality
$$ A^\top P A \preccurlyeq \sigma^2 P $$
holds if $\sigma$ is the maximum singular value of $A$.

Comment: The inequality $ A^\top P A \preccurlyeq \sigma^2 P $ denotes that $ \sigma^2 P - A^\top P A $ is positive semidefinite. The statement is true for $P=I$, directly by the definition of singular value.

Comment: I have tried with $P$ equal to the identity matrix and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this solution but it seems it can be negative definite!

$\begin{array}{l}
I = {x^T}\left\{ {{\sigma ^2}P - {A^T}PA} \right\}x = {\sigma ^2}{x^T}Px - {\left( {Ax} \right)^T}P\left( {Ax} \right)\\
{\sigma ^2}{\lambda _{\min }}\left( P \right){\left\| x \right\|^2} \le {\sigma ^2}{x^T}Px \le {\sigma ^2}{\lambda _{\max }}\left( P \right){\left\| x \right\|^2}\\
{\sigma ^2}{\lambda _{\min }}\left( P \right){\left\| x \right\|^2} \le {\left( {Ax} \right)^T}P\left( {Ax} \right) \le {\sigma ^2}{\lambda _{\max }}\left( P \right){\left\| x \right\|^2}\\
 \Rightarrow {\sigma ^2}{\lambda _{\min }}\left( P \right){\left\| x \right\|^2} - {\sigma ^2}{\lambda _{\max }}\left( P \right){\left\| x \right\|^2} \le I
\end{array}$

Comment: I think the following matrices can be used to show it's not true:

$\begin{array}{l}
P = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
a&0\\
0&b
\end{array}} \right]\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{}&{}
\end{array}0 < b < a\\
A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&{ - 1}\\
{ - 1}&0
\end{array}} \right]
\end{array}$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should I multiply the RHS by some specific constant?

Comment: Yes if you multiply by $\alpha$ where $\frac{{{\lambda _{\max }}(P)}}{{{\lambda _{\min }}(P)}} \le \alpha$

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in general.

Take $P=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ for example.
Then, $\sigma^2 P-A^\top P A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-2\\-2&0\end{pmatrix}\not\succeq 0$.